# How to decompile files from PyInstaller PYZ file

Tags: python, decompiling, pyinstaller

I have exe build by pyinstaller, so, i unpack it, and now i want unpack file *.pyz, where containing all script files, but filenames without extensions (only file names and is_packet in tuple True\False). Example files list, where return Zlib

```
BeautifulSoup
ConfigParser
HTMLParser
PyQt4
Queue
StringIO
UserDict
_LWPCookieJar
_MozillaCookieJar
__future__
_abcoll
_strptime
_threading_local
```

How you can see, files without extensions and all files encrypted. Example this unpacked files: http://www.sendspace.com/file/pky00m

So, how i can decompile it? Thanks

Comment: a pyz file is a zipped file. Use the archiveviewer.py provided with pyinstaller to view and extract such archives

Answer (score 14):

I have written a **[python script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyinstallerextractor/)** which will take a pyinstaller generated exe file and extract its contents including the PYZ file and every thing within

After using that script use **[Easy Python Decompiler](http://sourceforge.net/projects/easypythondecompiler/)** to decompile the generated pyc files.

If you are more interested ,
I have written a detailed paper on reversing such an application. Here is the link.

http://tuts4you.com/download.php?view.3541

Comment: How do you determine which decompiled .pyc is the "entry" script, versus all the modules and library files?

Comment: @Demonslay335 The entry script is usually located in the root directory within the decompiled folder. It is kept as-is (i.e not pyc compiled) within the CArchive. Hence you can try opening those files in a text editor to find out the one.

Comment: Looks promising.  I get: SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 841-842: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: Be careful with "Easy Python Decompiler". It may contain "Trojan horse" as an example. I haven't found this software at open source.

Comment: Well, I can verify that this should be marked as the correct answer. The tools do as described and work very well. Thanks a lot for your efforts!