# Where does pyinstaller store's python script?

Tags: python-3.x, exe, pyinstaller

I created executable(.exe) using pyinstaller. I would like to extract python code stored by pyinstaller. How to get it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to decompile files from PyInstaller PYZ file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18303122/how-to-decompile-files-from-pyinstaller-pyz-file)

Comment: Pyinstaller stores python scrips in .pyd file. I tried the solution you provided, it failed to detect PYZ, .pyd files.

Comment: i wanted to post this instead by SO does not allow sister sites: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/160/how-do-you-reverse-engineer-an-exe-compiled-with-pyinstaller